# How do I avoid saving Excel files in the temp directory in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, microsoft-office, file-management, microsoft-excel-2007

How do I make sure that I don't save files (Excel in this case) in `C:\Documents and Settings\u.sername\Local Settings\Temp`? (Apart from having my brain in gear!)

It's kind of disconcerting to save a file, and then not be able to find it in your usual location, nor have it listed amongst `My Recent Documents` or in the list of recent documents within Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen when you open an Excel file from an Internet link or email attachment?

My wife has done this a few times where she opens an attachment, makes changes, then can't find the files in her My Documents, so she re-opens the attachment, which saves over the file in the Temp folder.  Hours of work lost.

My recommendation is to always use `File -> "Save As..."`.  On the left side, make sure to select My Documents.

If you do end up saving a file in the Temp folder, use the Recent list in Excel (in the `File` menu) to open the last used file and do `Save As...` to re-save it.

I suppose the only *real* way around this would be to create an Excel plugin that would check each save operation to see if "Temp" is in the path and prompt to confirm.  *Actually, that sounds like a great idea...*

Comment: It's with files I created from scratch, but I'd been looking at attachments from Thunderbird recently.

Comment: It may have remembered your last used folder (from Thunderbird) and is defaulting there.  Instead of opening attachments directly, save them first and then open the saved file.